# .NET 4.8 + checking equality between two generic type parameters in the Where clause

Tags: c#, linq, generics, linq-to-entities

I am implementing repository pattern for an application i'm building, where my base repository is composed of two types: `TEntity` and `TKey`.

`TKey` is `struct` and `TEntity` is a custom class named: `BaseEntity<TKey>` where inside there is a single `virtual TKey Id` parameter that all DB models inherit:

```cs
    public abstract class BaseEntity { }

    public abstract class BaseEntity<TKey> : BaseEntity
        where TKey : struct
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
    }
```

in the concrete DB class:

```cs
    public class Products : BaseEntity<int>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Descrizione { get; set; }
        
        // ...
    }
```

Within the repository I managed all the cases that interests the application, except for a single method that I am developing called `FindAsync`, where I am having problems checking the equality of two `TKey` types within the `Where clause`:

```cs
public class BaseRepository<TEntity, TKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TKey>
    where TEntity : BaseEntity<TKey>, new()
    where TKey : struct
{
    public DBContext Context { get; }
    public DbSet<TEntity> Table { get; }

    public BaseRepository(DBContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        Table = Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual async Task<TEntity> FindAsync(TKey id, bool asNoTracking = false, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (asNoTracking)
        {
            return await Table.AsNoTracking()
                .Where(e => Equals(e.Id, id))
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken) ?? new TEntity();
        }
        else
        {
            return await Table.FindAsync(id, cancellationToken) ?? new TEntity();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

when I run my `FindAsync` method, while running the Where clause (and the `Equals(id, id)` method inside) a `NotSupportedException` is thrown indicating the following message:

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only >supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

I also tried with a different approach, where in the method depending on the type I execute the where converting the parameters to the type I expect for example:

```cs
public virtual async Task<TEntity> FindAsync(TKey id, bool asNoTracking = false, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    if (asNoTracking)
    {
        if (typeof(TKey) == typeof(int))
        {
            return await Table.AsNoTracking()
                .Where(e => Convert.ToInt32(e.Id) == Convert.ToInt32(id))
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken) ?? new TEntity();
        }

        // ...
    }
    else
    {
        return await Table.FindAsync(id, cancellationToken) ?? new TEntity();
    }
}
```

but another Exception is thrown indicating the following message:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

There is a way to include this type of control inside the `where clause` or, for example, I am forced to use the filter after having already enumerated the query result?

Comment: If this is to be translated to SQL, would not all IDs have a consistent type? I would expect the Id to be the Primary Key, and all databases I have seen use either an auto incremented long or a Guid for the PK.

Comment: `Where<T,bool>` is already generic. The expression it expects is already generic. What you try to do has nothing to do with generics though and suggests serious design issues. You could just use `_context.Orders.FindAsync(someID)` to load an **entity** (not table, not row) by its ID. Why are you even writing this `FindAsync` method? Why aren't the table's PK and the entity's PK the same type? That **matters**, because filtering by a function's results prevents the database from using indexes. The indexes were bult using the original column values, not the function results.

Answer (score -1):

**SOLVED**

specifying a `IComparable<TKey> constraint` in class declarations and comparing the two types using the `CompareTo()` method which the `IComparable` interface exposes:

```cs
public abstract class BaseEntity<TKey> : BaseEntity
    where TKey : struct, IComparable<TKey>
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Repository<TEntity, TKey> : IRepository<TEntity, TKey>
    where TEntity : BaseEntity<TKey>, new()
    where TKey : struct, IComparable<TKey>
{
    public DBContext Context { get; }
    public DbSet<TEntity> Table { get; }

    public BDConsulenzaRepository(DBContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        Table = Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual async Task<TEntity> FindAsync(TKey id, bool asNoTracking = false, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (asNoTracking)
        {
            return await Table.AsNoTracking()
                .Where(e => e.Id.CompareTo(id) == 0) // <-- using the int.CompareTo() method
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken) ?? new TEntity();
        }
        else
        {
            return await Table.FindAsync(id, cancellationToken) ?? new TEntity();
        }
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

the `CompareTo()` method is supported by `linq-to-entities`, and therefore the query is executed correctly returning the correct result (the comparison between the two types occurs correctly).

The only thing I need to understand is who actually implements the `CompareTo()` method.

Comment: Not really. `Where` had no problem, it was already generic. What you wrote though had several problems and now has even more. EF like all ORMs deals with entities, not tables. LINQ queries are translated to SQL. What you did will result in the most inefficient query possible, scanning the entire table to find matches. You could just use `_context.Orders.FindAsync(someKey)` already. The very class you wrote is a notorious antipattern too. A DbSet is *already* a single-entity Repositoyr, a DbContext is a multi-entity repo and UoW.

Comment: Going further in the design bugs, `Set<TEntity>()` only works because the metadata was calculated *and cached* through the DbContext's DbSet properties. You're trying to cover up a higher-level abstraction like an ORM (EF Core in this case) under a low-level abstraction like this single-entity "repository". Things have already broken down

Comment: Also I can't stress enough that those are entities, not tables. The whole point of ORMs is to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables and SQL. This non-repository class reverses this and brings tables back into the business code. I even suspect it's full of CRUD methods, which means it's a Data Access Object, not a Repository implementation at all

Comment: so this explanations in the official MS docs about implementing a generic repository for the unit of work is an antipattern?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Yes. Did you notice the product versions? EF5, MVC4, VS 2012? Although that was wrong back then too and highly controversial, with complaints going back [even further](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton). The link is from Ayende, the maintainer of NHibernate at the time (he knows a bit about ORMs and repos) and the creator of RavenDB (knows a bit about databases). Such "repositories" are hated by both C# MVPs and DBAs alike. Not so much by course and book authors, because they're easy to talk and describe

Comment: Can you spot the concurrency conflicts in the MS article? A DbContext is a *disconnected* Unit-of-Work. It means it tracks all changes without requiring an open connection to the database, much less a transaction. When you call `SaveChanges` a new connection is opened and all changes persisted at once. IDENTITY columns are resolved at this time by the DbContext itself. If you don't call `SaveChanges`, the changes are discarded when the DbContext is disposed. UoW for free. Now guess what almost all code using "repositories" does? Call SaveChanges after every change, so now they need explicit TX

Comment: Did you spot the *misnamed* methods? That `Update` doesn't update anything. It only attaches a *detached* object in the `Modified` state. Since DbContext tracks the entities it loaded, it already knows which ones have changed. It doesn't need to be told that.

Comment: Ok, what you say is very clear.
But then, at this point the same UoW what sense does it make if in the documentation and in the various examples (relating to web apps in .net) they always wrap the DbContext and the various repositories (or the generic repo) classes?

Comment: I was just getting to it. What does that "generic" UoW class do? Nothing, except delegate `SaveChanges` and `Dispose` to DbContext. And provide access to the entities in the same way that DbContext does. In that sense it's a million times better than implementations floating around SO, where people put a `BeginTransaction` and `CommitTransaction` inside the "UoW".

Comment: `what sense does it make` how did you end up with a `Find` that uses the wrong key type? And how many "generic repos" actually work this way? Far more call `SaveChanges` on every call. Not knowing how something works or why something is done changes it into a cargo cult. When things break people don't know why and blame the database, EF or their "big" 50K row tables

Comment: Using a Repository *does* make sense, provided it raises the abstraction level, either in a business or technology sense. When you already have an ORM, a *specialized* repository can hide the LINQ queries and data access patterns used by the ORM. That's closer to a "service" than a "repo" though. In a Blazor application you may or may not have an ORM - Blazor Server runs on the server so can use ORMs but Blazor WASM runs on the browser and talks to services. Of course, in that case the CRUD "repository" is inadequate as well.

Comment: then at this point i might as well not use a unit of work, because the DBContext is self-disposing and its might as well to call its savechanges method directly?